# Windows w32tm not answering NTP requests

Tags: windows, networking, time, ntp

I'm trying to setup an NTP server on my Windows machine. I'll give you a quick overview of the architecture I'm aiming for:

The setup is as follows: on the Windows computer there are two network interfaces, one that goes to internet, and another that communicates with local components, namely a router. The idea is to have a whole network isolated from internet where all ports are open and I can do what I want, with only the windows computer as the point of access, so that its firewall is protecting the whole LAN.

The problem is that the router on the LAN side can't sync its clock since I'm not sharing the internet connection, so I'm trying to have Windows provide the NTP data it gets from the internet.

As of now I can see that the NTP server is enabled on the Windows machine, and `w32tm` is running:

```
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
```

I can see that it's listening on `123` by running `netstat -aon`:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*
```

I also activated the logs, and disabled the firewall completely for the time of testing.

But the router simply doesn't sync.

If I connect another computer on the LAN (also with its firewall disabled) and run `w32tm /monitor /computers:x.x.x.x` I get this:

```
x.x.x.x[x.x.x.x:123]:
    ICMP: 0ms delay
    NTP: error ERROR_TIMEOUT - no response from server in 1000ms
```

How can the ping reach but not the NTP packet?

In the logs I don't see any trace that the computer even got a request. At this point I don't know what to look for, if you could nudge me in the proper direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I don't have a quick and obvious answer but I would suggest you review the following two sites to see if either provides an ah-ha moment: `https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/otlink-wo/How-to-Configure-a-Local-NTP-Server.html` `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings?tabs=config`

Comment: Haha it turns out those are the exact 2 pages I read before starting! Thanks for your help though, it just goes to show how limited documentation is on this topic. I followed every step, but I think something is missing, I'll keep digging

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was a firewall all along, just not the windows firewall. I was so stuck on the computer I didn't look at the router. If you try a setup like this make sure that all ports are open every step of the way and it'll work fine.